# Issues with closures and "this" keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, this

I am trying to create a simple JavaScript Calculator. However, when I run my code and make a change to any of the three fields (value box or sign) I get an error stating

> this.calculate is not a function

The error comes up under the this.calculate for whichever prototype function is being called depending on if you change your numerical value or the formula sign.

I've read up on closures, callbacks and the "this" keyword and I believe the issue lies somewhere there with how I am calling my prototype functions. Would someone help explain where in my code I am making a mistake and how to resolve it?

Here is the JavaScript

```
    var Formula=function() {
    this.value1 = null;
    this.value2 = null;
    this.sign = null;
    this.result = null;
};

Formula.prototype.calculate = function() {
    switch (this.sign) {
    case '+':
        this.result = this.value1 + this.value2;
        break;
    case '-':
        this.result = this.value1 - this.value2;
        break;
    case '/':
        this.result = this.value1 / this.value2;
        break;
    case '*':
        this.result = this.value1 * this.value2;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    } 
    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = this.result;
};

Formula.prototype.updateValue = function(event) {
    if (event.currentTarget.id === '#value1')
        this.value1 = parseFloat( event.currentTarget.value );
    else this.value2 = parseFloat( event.currentTarget.value );
    this.calculate();
};

Formula.prototype.updateSign = function(event) {
    this.sign = event.currentTarget.value;
    this.calculate();
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
(function() {
    var equation = new Formula();
    document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('change', equation.updateSign);
    var values = document.querySelectorAll('.value');
    for (var i = 0, numValues = values.length; i < numValues; i++) {
        values[i].addEventListener('change', equation.updateValue);
    }
})();
});
```

And here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="calcJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" class="value" id="value1"/>
<select id="sign">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">*</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
</select>
<input type="number" class="value" id="value2"/> 
= 
<span id="result"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Please do not deface your post after you have taken help from it. It is like cutting down a tree after taking shelter below it. Please allow the other future users to gain from the knowledge. The answerers would have put a lot of effort. Do not put their valuable time to waste.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to redo the code and put in the changes and ask a different question instead making a whole other post.

Comment: @sota7green don't do that either xD If you have another question, *ask another question*, don't edit the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` value in a function depends on how the function is called.

Generally when you do

```
var equation = new Formula();

equation.updateSign();
```

`this` would be the "Formula object" inside `updateSign`

However, when you do this

```
var equation = new Formula();
document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('change', equation.updateSign);
```

you're referencing the function, not calling it, the event handler eventually calls it, setting the `this` value to the changed element, not the `equation` object

If you want `this` to be the object instead, you'd have to do something like

```
var equation = new Formula();
document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('change', function() {
    equation.updateSign(arguments);
});
```

or using bind to return a new function with a set `this` value

```
var equation = new Formula();
document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('change', equation.updateSign.bind(equation));
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/68oj4be8/)

You also had a logical flaw

```
if (event.currentTarget.id === '#value1')
```

The ID is always returned without the hash

```
if (event.currentTarget.id === 'value1')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been reading up on bind/apply and trying to wrap my head around it but your explanation made it click! For some reason the actual equation doesn't print the right results for me when I pull up the HTML in the browser but it works in your fiddle. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @sota7green - I fixed a small error with the returned ID to make the fiddle work, but forgot to add that in the answer.

Comment: Is there any way to have the equation execute as soon as both value boxes are filled? For example I enter 3 and 4 into the boxes without changing the default '+' sign and have it run immediately without changing the operator sign?

Comment: Sure, you just start out with `this.sign` being the `+` and check that both values are given, like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/68oj4be8/1/

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're seeing is due to the way that event handling works.  When an event handler is called, `this` is implicitly passed to the handler function as the element that is the target of the event.

In order to do keep the original `this` scope, you'll need to wrap your function and invoke it directly. For example:

```
var equation = new Formula();

document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('change', function(event) 
{ 
    equation.updateSign(event); 
});
```

This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt4wn35n/) helps to illustrate.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. When I enter in my values for some reason the results are not correct. It seems to only print out the first number and make it positive or negative depending on the sign. Is there something wrong with my .calculate function?

Comment: Looks like adeneo already caught the error here, which he called out as a logical flaw in his answer.